# How Can I Create A Textbox that inserts html into The Webpage Using Only JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, button, input

I'm creating an XSS vulnerable website for one of my friends so he can mess around with it. However, I've been trying to create one for the past few days but it hasn't been working. What I have now just to simplify it is:

```
<input type="text" id="YourText">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Button</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("YourText").value);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

So what it's supposed to do is if you press the button called button, it creates a button with the text you typed into the text box that has the id of your create. However, when I run this, nothing happens. I don't understand why. I've used paragraph tags and even script tags but nothings working. However, if I make it so it only creates the element but doesn't take input from the user, like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hi"));
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

It works just fine. I've tried removing the .value but it still doesn't work. I just can't understand what I'm doing wrong, please help.

The source code for it is here: https://github.com/ninja25538/SuperCoolImageSiteThat-sNotAtAllVulnerable/blob/master/index.html

Comment: I'd like to use only JavaScript but if there is no option with JavaScript, I'll use Jquery

Comment: You have a typo: the parentheses are not balanced in your code snippets. If you would have monitored the console, you would have noticed.

Comment: My computer doesn't have console since it's blocked =(

Comment: [How do I open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: No as in I'm using a school owned chromebook, I'm allowed to do what I'd like on it, but they have the ability to block inspect element and websites

Comment: Did you correct the typo?

Comment: Yep, it still isn't working, I also put the entire source code into the question and here's where it runs:https://ninja25538.github.io/SuperCoolImageSiteThat-sNotAtAllVulnerable/

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list". [Added the parenthesis here.](https://jsfiddle.net/nx9emqnn/)

Comment: The source code referred to in your question still has the typo.... I am moving on. This is taking too long. Sorry.

Comment: @trincot it's fine, I get it bro, there are better questions and you have a life to live

Comment: It's creating the button now, however, there's no text inside the button

Comment: Have you typed anything into the text input? [Working here](https://jsfiddle.net/nx9emqnn/1/).

Comment: It's working now, thanks @showdev!

Comment: Why did my question get down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var val = document.getElementById("YourText").value;
var x = "<input type=submit value="+val+"></input>";
document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML += x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("YourText").value);
```

try

```
btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("YourText").innerHTML);
```